# How to play audio file ios

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play an audio file but I can get it working.
I imported the `AVFoundation` framework.

Here is the code:

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alarm" ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fileName];
    NSLog(@"Test: %@ ", url);

    AVAudioPlayer *audioFile = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
    audioFile.delegate = self;
    audioFile.volume = 1;

    [audioFile play];
```

I am receiving an error `nil string parameter`

I copied the file to the supporting files folder so the file is there.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that when you select that file in Xcode, its "Target Membership" section is set (in the properties window the left most tab)

Comment: After doing that I am not receiving an error but the sound does not play. The path that I am given is 'file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/FAA680BA-162E-4E58-A22B-3E2F139A4368/RemindMe.app/Alarm.caf'

Comment: I bet the reason it doesn't play is because it goes out of scope and gets deallocated before it has a chance.  Make it an instance variable so it sticks around.

Comment: And the answer is... You are right :) I created a property and now it is working. Do you know why this happen?

Comment: Yes, for the reason I said above...ARC will deallocate variables at the end of the scope they are in if no strong references remain.

Comment: @Camus Please mark an answer as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow two simple steps

Step1:

UIViewController.h

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@property(nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

Step 2:

UIViewController.m

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" 
                                                      ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

 _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
[_player setVolume:1.0];
[_player play];
```

Just make sure AVAudioPlayer property must be nonatomic and retain.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this when the file is in a specific folder:

```
// Build URL to the sound file we are going to play
NSURL *sound_file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound_file_name ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:directory]];   

// Play it
audio_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:sound_file error:nil];
audio_player.delegate = self;
[audio_player play];
[sound_file release];
```

`sound_file_name` is the file name name without the extension: `@"success"`

`directory` is something like: `@"media/sound_effects"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this and see if the program recognizes the file exists.

`NSLog(@"File Exists:%d",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName]);`

It will print a 1 if it exists. If not make sure you have the proper filename (case matters).

Comment: Try`NSError *error;
 AVAudioPlayer *audioFile = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];  
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [error description]);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import your audiotoolbox framework and then write the following. This is what I use to play simple sounds

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

 CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Your sound here", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

If you have any confusion with this let me know.